# Best practice for displaying user info on home page with GET request

Tags: node.js, express, get, server, handlebars.js

My Node.js (Express) server keeps track of whether or not the user is logged in.

If the user is logged in and the homepage is requested, it serves the **homepage** with the **user's name in the top hand corner**. Otherwise, it just serves the normal homepage. This is done with handlebars.js.

I read that GET requests are supposed to be idempotent. I'm not sure if doing this violates this rule. www.google.com, for example, loads your icon and email in the top right corner. Is what I'm doing okay? If not, what is the **best practice**?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fine and considered 'normal' behaviour. I'd argue that making a page truly idempotent would be a vary hard task on most 'dynamic' website although it might vary site-site though.

With a bit of re-engineering it might be possible, for example let's say you have an application that requires authentication, instead of sending the user back to the homepage which now renders the user's dashboard, you could instead route it to '`/dashboard` which would, for the most part, be classed as idempotent ('`/dashboard`' would always show the dashboard).